# Building .exe files from C# with Visual Studio that keep dependencies

Tags: c#

When I go into my bin debug folder and move the exe out of it, which depends on a library I have installed in Visual Studio, it will crash because it can no longer find the library it needs.

I was wondering how you can build a library into the app so it will be able to run anywhere instead of just in the bin/debug folder.

Thanks!

Comment: What else is in your output folder? Are there the referenced DLLs?

Comment: You can configure for every reference weather it will copied to the output folder or not. So you just have to copy your referenced *.dlls. I don't know why this should a bad idea in general. An installer on the other hand would be the "cleaner" solution.

Answer (score 0):

you have 3 options.

1) create an installer. this is a decent way: http://wixtoolset.org/

(we use http://www.advancedinstaller.com/) it works well but expensive.

2)**bad idea**  embedd the dlls inside the exe

3) **bad idea**  just copy all the referenced files

Comment: You can't say that WIX is the official way. It is one way that is very effective albeit with a high learning curve. In my time I have used Advanced Installer, InstallShield, Batch Scripts, and I have even rolled out my own installers. Each method has pros and cons and it is not really possible to say that one way is the "Official Way"

Comment: wix is free but annoying.
advance installer is easy but expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you ask for static linking of `dll` files, which is not the intended approach; the question can be seen as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102296/how-to-statically-link-libraries-for-a-c-sharp-classlibrary).